# Property is nil after having been assigned

Tags: ios, objective-c

The private property declared as:

```
@interface Camera ()
{
    SE3 *_transformationFromWorld;
}
@end
```

Is assigned when the `Camera` object is initialized:

```
self = [super init];
SE3 *transformation = [[SE3 alloc] initWithRotation:R withTranslation:T];
_transformationFromWorld = transformation;
[self initIntrinsics];

return self;
```

But in the debugger window I can see it remains `nil`, while the `transformation` object is assigned normally. (I expanded the code to check that it wasn't the `SE3` initialization method returning a `nil`)

How is this possible?

**SOLUTION:**

Comments from @Shahar pointed me to the right direction. When I declared the property like this (always in the .m file):

```
@interface Camera ()
@property SE3 *transformationFromWorld;
@end
```

it magically worked. Someone care to explain the difference between this way of declaring the property and the previous one?

Comment: The object gets deleted after the method is finished. You need to process global variables in your constructor if you want them.

Comment: Shouldn't the `_transformationFromWorld` pointer keep it alive? If I assign directly to the private var, the private var stays nil. That doesn't happen for the local var `transformation` though.

Comment: I'm not sure but it doesn't seem like it does from your experimentation ^_^.

Comment: I declared the property like `__strong SE3 *_transformationFromWorld;` but that didn't help. That code is the code of the constructor, by the way.

Comment: What do you do inside of initIntrinsics?

Comment: There is no difference other than with the solution setters and getters are automatically created. I suspect you are testing for the wrong thing on the debugger. Create a method that tests for the var within your class. Then initialize your object, and call your method to test.

Comment: try check self on nil before using an instance variables